# Как на wordpress сайте добавить код в контент после определенного <div>?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ранее для добавления рекламного кода после определенного по счету `</h2>` пользовался следующим кодом

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_ad_content');

function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 2; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("</h2>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">';
            $new_content.= 'Рекламный блок';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</h2>";
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Теперь надо добавить код после закрывающего `</div>` определенного класса
В каждой записи есть блок поделиться от яндекса, он обернут в `<div class="ya-share2">` вот после этого закрывающего `</div>` и требуется добавить код.

Comment: что мешает просто добавить этот код в том шаблоне, в котором вы выводите блок яндекса?

Comment: Дело в том что кнопки поделиться были добавлены вручную в каждую статью отдельно (т.е. находятся в "теле" статьи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на странице один ya-share2 и между `<div class="ya-share2">` и нужным `</div>` нет других `</div>`, то должно помочь:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_ad_content');

function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;

    $new_content = '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">';           
    $new_content.= 'Рекламный блок';
    $new_content.= '</div>';

    $content = explode("ya-share2", $content, 2);
    $add_content = explode("</div>", $content[1], 2);
    $add_content[1] =  $new_content.$add_content[1];
    $new_content = $content[0] . "ya-share2" . $add_content[0]."</div>" . $add_content[1];

    return $new_content;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло.